# Панча Сила

Tags: орфография, история

Панча Сила (pañca śīla) - это с санскрита "пять принципов", основа конституции и официальной идеологии Индонезии. На индонезийском пишут в одно слово  "Pancasila". Среди российских и советских историков и политологов я встречал пять видов написания слова:

1. Панча Сила (самое распространённое и самое раннее написание),
2. Панча сила,
3. Панчасила,
4. Панча-сила,
5. панча сила,

Не считая совсем редких вариантов. При этом "Панча" не склоняется, а "сила" склоняется по первому склонению.

**Вопрос:** Как правильнее будет записать этот термин?

Comment: А из чего исходить-то? Нет общих принципов на такие случаи. Потому, видимо, и бардак такой в существующих написаниях.
Тут, имхо, может быть только авторитетное закрепление.   
Я откуда в Индонезии санскрит?

Comment: >Я [А] откуда в Индонезии санскрит?

@behemothus, там довольно много индуистов. Термин придумал первый президент Индонезии, Ахмед Сукарно, у которого мать происходила из брахманов острова Бали.

Comment: Да про индуистов-то я знаю. Но разве они не на индонезийском (вернее сказать - малайском) говорят? Это совершенно другая языковая семья, а Индонезия в числе стран распространения санскрита не значится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в "Большом Российком энциклопедическом словаре" и "Словаре политических терминов" написано" Панча Шила",а у Лопатина панча-шила
http://lopatin.academic.ru/92636/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0,

Здесь -  Панча Сила http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/118325/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0

В общем, кто как хочет.

Answer (score 2):

Ну короче, логичнее писать по варианту 3.
Ближе к оригиналу, а других весомых аргументов за или против я не вижу. 
Тем более что на английском тоже пишут именно так - с заглавной и слитно.

Comment: Ну, тогда нужно писать хальстух, а не галстук. Это в английском, там так пришло, у нас так. Вот Лопатин у нас теперь норму даёт, по нему, наверно, и должны писать.А как дальше будет - увидим.

Comment: Можно и "хальстух". Если бы это соответствовало современному произношению и общим принципам транслитерации - то было бы и нужно.

Английский нам не указ, но уж точно не стоит выбирать вариант "чтобы было не как у них", даже если другого разумного подхода.

А Лопатин, судя по всему, даже не знает, что это за зверь такой. Откуда там Ш взялось, можно поинтересоваться? Чтобы было не как в английском?

Comment: >Откуда там Ш взялось, можно поинтересоваться?

Это уже заимствование от китайцев. И обозначает разные понятия. Причём панча-шила (пять принципов мирного сосуществования) может быть Панча Силой, а Панча Сила (индонезийские принципы) панча-шилой не называют. Где-то читал, что как раз на санскрите правильным будет, вариант через "ш".

По поводу распространённости санскрита в Индонезии, сказать ничего не могу, но для одного человека, к тому же полиглота, статистика распространености не действует.

 Панча Шила - это ещё и заповеди в буддизме.